# How to check validity of password for wifi network

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, wifi

Basically i have info such as the network interface, name of the wifi network, password, etc, and i am trying to check if the wifi password is correct by trying to log into the wifi with it and getting the received message to check if it is correct or not. So far i have tried to connect to a wifi network using the network setup command line command which worked until i tried getting the output from it into the application, so i was wondering if anyone knows a simple way i can use that command line tool with the application or any built in ways i could use that would not rely on command line.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should try [CoreWLAN Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Reference/CoreWLANFrameworkRef/_index.html). Documentation is poor, but framework is simple and there is an [example](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CoreWLANWirelessManager/Introduction/Intro.html) (it is somewhat outdated and you'll get some deprecation warnings)

Answer (score 0):

on a Mac you can use this line of bash in Terminal to log into a wifi network:

```
networksetup -setairportnetwork port networkname password
```

***if the password is wrong, Error -3905 will be returned***

*Note:*

**port** is your wifi port (on my Mac it's port en0)

**networkname** is the name of the network, like Starbucks

**password** is just the straight up password for the network

if the password is already saved in your keychain you don't need that param